# Oracle SQL How to set low priority to not disturb live system?

Tags: sql, oracle, thread-priority

I need to make sql query on an oracle live system. I am not very experienced with SQL and have never worked with a Oracle Live System. I know very little about the System only that it has limited server capicity. And it is very important. So what should not happen is that my query takes to much resources from the server so that the live system gets slowed done or crashes. That would be hugh mess. Can i set the priority of my query to very low? I have time, if it takes an hour or five it does not matter but the system has to be stable all of the time. Or can i adapt my code in a way that makes it as simple as possible for the system to answer the query.

I have a List of CaseNr for them i need Infos from the System. The System has 3 Tables that are of interesst for me. P contains the CaseNr that i need and some extra Infos thats straight forward. There will only be 1 row per CaseNr. A contains CaseNr and AANR this AANR i need for my question in the Table M. There can be more than one AANR per CaseNr. And at least M that does not contain the variable CaseNr but has multiple rows per AANR where i only need the MWSTR Variable vor specific Values of UUNR.

Here is my SQL Code:

```
/* PATLIST */
CREATE TABLE PATLIST
  (StudyNR   char(6), Case CaseNr  char(8));

  INSERT INTO PATLIST
    VALUES('1001', '100001')
    VALUES('1002', '100002')
    VALUES('1003', '100003')
    VALUES('1004', '100004')
    VALUES('1005', '100005')
    VALUES('1006', '100006')
    VALUES('1007', '100007')
    VALUES('1008', '100008')
    VALUES('1009', '100009')
    VALUES('1010', '100010');
    /* ... Total 529 */

    CREATE TABLE Labordat AS
        SELECT L.StudyNR, L.CaseNr,
               P.PPNR, P.GESC AS SEX, P.Life, P.AufnDAT, P.EntlDAT,
               A.AANR, A.AFNR, A.ETIM,
               (SELECT M.MWSTR FROM MESSWERT M
                    WHERE A.AANR = M.AANR AND M.lBIT ='TRUE' AND M.UUNR = 'Value1')
                AS AST,
               (SELECT M.MWSTR FROM MESSWERT M
                    WHERE A.AANR = M.AANR AND M.lBIT ='TRUE' AND M.UUNR = 'Value2')
                AS ALT,
               (SELECT M.MWSTR FROM MESSWERT M 
                    WHERE A.AANR = M.AANR AND M.lBIT ='TRUE' AND M.UUNR = 'Value3')
                AS ALP,
               (SELECT M.MWSTR FROM MESSWERT M
                    WHERE A.AANR = M.AANR AND M.lBIT ='TRUE' AND M.UUNR = 'Value4')
                AS BILI,
               (SELECT M.MWSTR FROM MESSWERT M
                    WHERE A.AANR = M.AANR AND M.lBIT ='TRUE' AND M.UUNR = 'Value5')
                AS BILIDIREKT
        FROM PATLIST L left outer join PAT P ON (L.CaseNr = P.Fall)
            left outer join AUF A ON (P.FALL = A.FALL);
```

Any suggestions and comments are welcome. Thanks in advance for your patients and time.

Comment: Do you have DBA privileges for this system, or does somebody else manage that side of things?

Oracle has something called the "Resource Manager", which basically allows the DBA to create different groups, and control how CPU resources are distributed among these groups (e.g. "reserving" a certain percentage of CPU time for certain users).

If you're just a user of the system, you would generally need to coordinate with DBAs in order to set this up.

Comment: I think we have just User Priviledge on this System. The managment is made by an external firm. So i will try to get contact and discuss this. But is there a way to write my query in a way that it needs less resources? Or that it splits up the task in thiny bits that can be done after each other would that help?

Comment: It is generally more efficient to execute a single, large query than to split it up. Just try to make sure that it is written in way which doesn't do unnecessary work, and uses appropriate indexes. Learning to read a query's execution plan helps a lot here. Splitting up a query into lots of smaller ones is often considerably slower overall - this *might* be a way to spread out the load on the system, but is a hacky solution at best - you're better off working with the DBAs, as they have tools to throttle or otherwise minimise the impact, and can advise on the best time to run it etc.